# Attach PDF document including text and image to Email C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am working on email sending module in which i have to add normal string text and following to that a barcode image data and should be attach as PDF type. But pdf is coming as shown below

some text here
......
text ends

```
<img
src='data:image/png;base64,Qk1mZgAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAA2gAAAB4AAAABAC..... alt='img'>
```

see my code below,

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
attachmentName = "invoice";
attachmentBody = new MemoryStream(att.Value); // byte[] format
string attachmentTypeTmp = "PDF"
attach = mailProxy.AttachReceipt(attachmentTypeTmp, attachmentName, attachmentBody);
//add attachment to mail message
message.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

Comment: You can use iTextSharp to transform a image in a PDF

Answer (score 0):

try using System.Net.Mail.Attcachment to set the conenttype to pdf. also you could use the using statement for the MemoryStream like this. With using the memory stream is automatically disposed afterwars and you don't need to by yourself.

```cs
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(att.Value) {
 Attachment at = new Attachment(ms, new ContentType("application/pdf"));
 at.ContentDisposition.FileName = "invoice.pdf";
 message.Attachments.Add(at);

//send inside using or you get an exception from the stream
smtp.send(message)
}
```

Comment: thanks for comment. but i'm getting image part as <img src='data:image/png;base64,Qk1mZgAAAAAAADYAAAAo.....>

Comment: then your byte[] is not a pdf but a png image. You need to convert it first to a pdf. have a look at janmacos comment and try iTextSharp